# Meteor , Javascript : Clean up or iterator only 10 of history

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I keep adding messages on the window, but I want to display only the last 10 messages. How do I do it? In jQuery, I can just use append and remove onto the list, but in Meteor I have something like this.

in html

```
<template name="messages">
    {{#each messages}}
       <strong>{{name}}</strong> : {{message}}<br>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I am looping through the messages, which makes my app display all the message. Then how do I select the only 10, not looping through the whole. Thanks!

```
 Template.messages.messages = function () {
     return Messages.find({}, { sort: { time: -1 }});
 }

 Template.input_box.events = {
     "keydown input#message" : function(event){
         if (event.which == 13) { 
        if (Meteor.user())
        {
            var name = Meteor.user().profile.name;
        }
        else
        {
            var name = "Anonymous";
        }

        var message = document.getElementById("message");

        var thetime = new Date();
        var time_string = "time "+thetime.getHours();
        if (message.value != "") {
            Messages.insert({
                name: name,
                message: message.value,
                time: time_string,
            });

            document.getElementById("message").value = "";
            message.value = "";
        }
    }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to display the messages, I would go even further and take them off the client's minimongo completely. Otherwise it will just fill up a cache you aren't using and pollute the merge box. The following publication will make all messages but the last 10 disappear on the client automatically:

```js
Meteor.publish("messages", function() {
    return Messages.find({}, {
        sort: { time: -1 },
        limit: 10
    });
});
```

A few notes:

- You should **compute timestamps on the server** because client timestamps are unreliable and messages won't necessarily appear in the order they were sent. Add a [deny hook](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq) or use [collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks).
- You may need to **sort the messages again on the client** in ascending order of timestamp, unless you are displaying them newest-first.
- Make sure you have **appropriate indexes on your Mongo collection** (especially on the `time` field) so that the server can efficiently track the last 10 messages.

  ```
  Messages._ensureIndex({time: 1});
  ```

  plus whatever other fields you are using. Consult http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/ for proper ordering if you are using compound indexes.